# Kivy's labels overlapping when dynamically resizing screen, how can i keep space between them?

Tags: python, kivy

My code creates lots of boxlayouts (with a label) inside another boxlayout (id: box). it's ok, but when the text is too long or i resize the screen it overlaps other labels, like this [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovmaF.png)

test.kv

```
<List>:
    BoxLayout:
        id:box
        padding:50
        spacing:200
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
<Item>:
    Label:
        id: label
        size_hint_y: None
        font_size:20
        text_size: self.width, None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
```

Class.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView



class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        list1 = []
        for i in range(4): list1.append(15 * "Long Text here, Long Text here, Long Text here,")
        return List(list1)


class List(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, text1, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for t in text1:
            self.ids.box.add_widget(Item(text = t))

class Item (BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, text = '', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.label.text = text

Test().run()
```

I've tried some things like changing the padding, text_size, height but didn't work and it was ugly, what can i do? 
I want to have a fixed, small gap between the "tweet" widgets inside of the BoxLayout (id:box)
*edited to include minimal example

Comment: Can you post a minimal *runnable* example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @inclement done

Comment: It looks like in your Item rule you should add `size_hint_y: None` and `height: self.minimum_height`. The problem is that right now your Item heights don't match the labels they contain.